# How can I install cocos2D's document into my Xcode Help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I download the cocos2d's package from http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/downloads/list.
My Mac has already install the doxygen.
But when I build the cocos-2d Document, lots of error occured.

like this:

error: problems opening map file /Developer/cocos2d-iphone-0.99.5/build/cocos2d-ios.build/Release-iphonesimulator/cocos2d-documentation.build/doxygen_output/html/_c_c_block_support_8h__incl.map for inclusion in the docs!

If you installed Graphviz/dot after a previous failing run,

try deleting the output directory and rerun doxygen.

How can i do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the following link.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/358

Answer (score -2):

I've written up a quick guide on installing cocos2d documentation [here](http://www.shaydesdsgn.com/post/3823738899/getting-cocos2d-documentation-in-xcode)